# Why are the cards overlapping for tablet screen size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So I've got 4 bootstrap cards and when I look at them for the tablet view they are overlapping. I've had to set the height and width of them in the html code because it wasn't working in the CSS. Here is my html code:

```
<div  class="container">
<div class="update">
 <h5>UPCOMING EVENTS</h5>
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
 <div class="col">
   <div class="card" style="width:300px">
     <img src="images/football.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="height:200px; width:300px">
     <div class="card-body"  >
       <h6 class="card-title  " >CARIBBEAN FOOTBALL</h6>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning  card_button" >VIEW MORE..</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  <div class="card" style="width:300px">
    <img src="images/football.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="height:200px; width:300px">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h6 class="card-title ">EVENT NAME</h6>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning card_button">VIEW MORE..</button>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
 <div class="col">
  <div class="card" style="width:300px">
    <img src="images/football.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="height:200px; width:300px">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h6 class="card-title ">EVENT NAME</h6>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning card_button">VIEW MORE..</button>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
 
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
 /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {}

.card {
width: 200px
}

.card-img-top {
height: 300px;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Here is what it looks like for the tablet screen size: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt739.png)

Answer (score 0):

The media query isn't doing anything...

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {}
```

The media query rules should be inside the brackets...

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  .card {
    width: 200px
  }

  .card-img-top {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

}
```

Additionally the inline styles (`style="width:300px"`) are always going to override the media query.

It's not a good idea to use absolute (pixel) widths for responsive behavior. Setting an absolute width on the cards will prevent the card from filling the width of the responsive (relative width) columns.

Comment: Hey I did put it inside the brackets but it still doesn't work

Comment: Like I said you shouldn't have px widths.. it's not responsive. Why are you setting width: 300px, width: 200px, etc...??